# can we change the asscoiated email-id with our account?

Tags: support, login

I use to login with my official email id on **dba.se**.

I want to update this i want to use my personal email-id  for login instead of official id.

how i will change this here i don't see any options for the same.

Comment: Did ... did you try going to your user profile, clicking edit, and .. changing the email address?

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to use a *different* Google Account to log in with, just go to your user page and click the **"my logins"** link:

[image]

You can then click the **"add more logins..."** link to start the process of adding more credentials to your account.